# DOM event of Google Map does not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Google provided some few example of how to create a custom legend on the map. Here's the code.

```
var legend = document.createElement('div');
legend.id = 'legend';
var content = [];
content.push('<h3><b>View option</b></h3>');
content.push('<div id="general"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="general" ></g><g><text x="26" y="10">General</text></g></svg></div>');
content.push('<div id="faculty"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="faculty"></g><g><text x="26" y="10">Faculty</text></g></svg></div>');
content.push('<div id="sexDiv"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="sex"></g><g><text x="26" y="10">Sex</text></g></svg></div>');
content.push('<div id="level"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="level"></g><g><text x="26" y="10">Level of education</text></g></svg></div>');

legend.innerHTML = content.join('');
legend.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(legend);
```

I'm trying to  make that legend interactive(display the data based on the legend clicked by user) using this code which is also from Google.

```
var sexOpt = document.getElementById("sexDiv");

google.maps.event.addDomListener(sexOpt, 'click', function() {
    window.alert('Sex was clicked!'); /*just to test*/
});
```

But, it does not listen to it. Previously, the class and id name is similar so I thought that would be a conflict (even it's obviously doesn't have) but it still does not listen.

Comment: If you `console.log(sexOpt)` what do you see? I'm guessing the element doesn't exist when you bind the event to it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: That looks like an error from a completely different part of your code. If you double click it it should take you to the offending line.

Comment: That's exactly because of what Rory said. You are sending null to the addDomListener function, check this, it is working when thing are in the right order https://jsfiddle.net/jhxdncc1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `<div id="sex">` isn't in the DOM when `document.getElementById("sexDiv")` is run.  One option is to wait for the `map` idle event, then run that code.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
  var sexOpt = document.getElementById("sexDiv");

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(sexOpt, 'click', function() {
    window.alert('Sex was clicked!'); /*just to test*/
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3oywrdo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var legend = document.createElement('div');
  legend.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  legend.style.padding = '5px';
  legend.id = 'legend';
  var content = [];
  content.push('<h3><b>View option</b></h3>');
  content.push('<div id="general"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="general" ></g><g><text x="26" y="10">General</text></g></svg></div>');
  content.push('<div id="faculty"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="faculty"></g><g><text x="26" y="10">Faculty</text></g></svg></div>');
  content.push('<div id="sexDiv"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="sex"></g><g><text x="26" y="10">Sex</text></g></svg></div>');
  content.push('<div id="level"><svg height="20" width="200"><g><rect width="15" height="12"class="level"></g><g><text x="26" y="10">Level of education</text></g></svg></div>');

  legend.innerHTML = content.join('');
  legend.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(legend);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    var sexOpt = document.getElementById("sexDiv");

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(sexOpt, 'click', function() {
      window.alert('Sex was clicked!'); /*just to test*/
    });
    var genOpt = document.getElementById("general");

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(genOpt, 'click', function() {
      window.alert('General was clicked!'); /*just to test*/
    });
    var facultyOpt = document.getElementById("faculty");

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(facultyOpt, 'click', function() {
      window.alert('Faculty was clicked!'); /*just to test*/
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: The same idea as Rory McCrossan's comment couple of minutes ago.

Comment: As the fiddle I posted 10 minutes ago.

Comment: thanks! Is it because the sexDiv is in the array? If it's not in the array will my previous code work?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the array. Please check previous comments for your original answer.

Comment: It is because sexDiv hasn't been rendered by the browser and is not in the DOM when you call `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @geocodezip I've created a 2nd layer legend which loaded into the map using the same method of the 1 legend except for it is loaded after the 1st layer legend are clicked. I've put the google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() in the  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() but, it only work for the top two event. How do I make 6 of them work?\

Comment: That is a new question.